# Can range based for loop work for assignment?

Tags: c++, for-loop, range

Is it possible to use/implement a ranged base loop to assign numbers to an array?

What I want:

```
for (auto i : X){
    i = 1;
} //I want this to fill the array with 1.
```

Comment: Next question: is there a good song about the downvote army?

Comment: Yes, it's called *"Google 'range for loop assign c++'"*. To be clear: Downvoted for lack of research effort.

Comment: But i made the class. it is not stl vector. so i skip those results about stl vector. Now i see the vector question uses the auto & i loop

Comment: Seems like a bad idea, given the answer is the same unless you don't show us something important.

Comment: @rxu Then make your question clearer next time, and show us what you made. However if its iteratable, a reference should just work fine.

Comment: I found it: https://www.google.com/search?q=down+vote+army&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=down+vote++bot

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is it possible to use/implement a ranged base loop to assign numbers to an array?

Yes, use a reference:

```
for (auto & i : X){
       // ^
    i = 1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. There is no performance penalty?

Comment: @rxu Performance penalty vs what?

Comment: @rxu There's performance benefit. Your original code makes a copy of every element, this doesn't copy.

Comment: vs accessing an array in contiguous memory with raw pointer.

Comment: @rxu No, references are as performant as raw pointers. No difference.